# How to get a Location's latitude and longitude at some distance between the two locations?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have route json reply from `google maps API`. route structure is something like..

```
{
"routes": [
    {
        "legs": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "1.8 mi",
                    "value": 2859
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "9 mins",
                    "value": 515
                },
                "end_location": {
                    "lat": 42.3781746,
                    "lng": -71.06022609999999
                },
                "start_address": "Boston, MA, USA",
                "start_location": {
                    "lat": 42.359824,
                    "lng": -71.05981249999999
                },
                "steps": [... ],
                "via_waypoint": []
            }
        ],
        "summary": "N Washington St and Chelsea St"
    }
],
"status": "OK"
```

}

I want to get a location containing `latitude` and `longitude` which is `1.2 kms` away from `start_location` and is in between the `path` to `end_location`.

Comment: Sounds like you want a waypoint.  I have some examples (using a version of [Mike Williams' epoly, ported to v3 of the API](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm)): [Marker at 9.5km and 64.8km](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html) and [Place marker on route based on time travelled](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-timeOnRoute.html)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip . Yes. That's exactly what I'm looking for. The waypoints !! Is there any Java API for the same? I mean a method that accepts a two locations namely _start_location_ and _end_location_ and a _distance_ parameter and returns the location details which is _distance_ kms away from _start_location_ and is in the path between _start_location_ and _end_location_.

Comment: I don't do java, sorry.

Comment: From the example [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js). If you view the source code, you will find `v3_epoly.js` in which contains `GetPointAtDistance` method. That's the js, but you can go ahead and change it to java, the algorism is the same.